# TestCafe + VPN can't open links without trailing slash

Tags: javascript, url, vpn, openvpn, testcafe

Connection to our website is through VPN.
When we try to use .navigateTo('https://mainwebsite.net/app1') TestCafe will not load that page, it will be infinite loading. But if we add / at the end of that url .navigateTo('https://mainwebsite.net/app1/') it will work. Same issue when clicking links. Tried on multiple machines, browsers and testcafe versions, still same issue. Where could be the problem?

Also to note, when using normal browser(not running testcafe) on VPN it works fine with or without trailing slash

Comment: It could be misconfigured url-rewrite rules on your web server, but it could be something else too.

Comment: Is VPN relevant?  If you use test cafe/browser not through VPN does it work?

Comment: Yes it did work when connected on the same network as our server, but atm we have to use VPN to connect to it. We used openVPN app with a config file configured by our IT and they don't know why this is happening. Is there some kind of config option we have to turn on?

Answer (score 3):

According to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55022700/testcafe-vpn-cant-open-links-without-trailing-slash#comment96826139_55022700), this situation is not a TestCafe problem.
Just need to find the problematic url-rewrite rule and fix it.